# jQuery - Loop through nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have multiple `div` elements having same class name (`listing_class`). What I need is to get `href` value of each anchor tag in all `div` elements respectively.

```js
var length = $(".listing_class").length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  $(".listing_class").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).children('a').attr('href'));
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listing_class " style="display: none;">
  <a href="?section=all&status=active" class="active"> All Listings</a>
  <a href="?section=sale&status=active" class="active"> For Sale (0)</a>
  <a href="?section=rent&status=active" class="active"> For Rent (0)</a>
</div>
<div class="listing_class " style="display: none;">
  <a href="?section=a&status=p" class="active"> a</a>
  <a href="?section=b&status=p" class="active"> b</a>
  <a href="?section=c&status=p" class="active"> c</a>
</div>
<div class="listing_class " style="display: none;">
  <a href="?section=QQ&status=FF" class="active"> a</a>
  <a href="?section=FF&status=FF" class="active"> b</a>
  <a href="?section=VV&status=FF" class="active"> c</a>
</div>
<div class="listing_class " style="display: none;">
  <a href="?section=WW&status=p"> VV</a>
  <a href="?section=WW&status=p"> CC</a>
  <a href="?section=WW&status=p"> AQ</a>
</div>
<div class="listing_class " style="display: none;">
  <a href="?section=A&status=p"> VV</a>
  <a href="?section=B&status=p"> CC</a>
  <a href="?section=X&status=p"> AQ</a>
</div>
```

Problem is, it returns anchor values of first div only and doesn't loop further.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically a better solution would be to find all the `a` elements under `.list_class` class is if you find with the following `jQuery` selector `$('.listing_class a')` all the `a` tags. Then this can be used to iterate through all the necessary items and get the `href` attribute of each elements.

Maybe you can try the following:

```js
$('.listing_class a').each(function(lc) {
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<div class="listing_class " style="display: none;">
    <a href="?section=all&status=active" class="active"> All Listings</a>
    <a href="?section=sale&status=active" class="active"> For Sale (0)</a>
    <a href="?section=rent&status=active" class="active"> For Rent (0)</a>
</div>
<div class="listing_class " style="display: none;">
    <a href="?section=a&status=p" class="active"> a</a>
    <a href="?section=b&status=p" class="active"> b</a>
    <a href="?section=c&status=p" class="active"> c</a>
</div>
<div class="listing_class " style="display: none;">
    <a href="?section=QQ&status=FF" class="active"> a</a>
    <a href="?section=FF&status=FF" class="active"> b</a>
    <a href="?section=VV&status=FF" class="active"> c</a>
</div>
<div class="listing_class " style="display: none;">
    <a href="?section=WW&status=p" > VV</a>
    <a href="?section=WW&status=p" > CC</a>
    <a href="?section=WW&status=p" > AQ</a>
</div>
<div class="listing_class " style="display: none;">
    <a href="?section=A&status=p"> VV</a>
    <a href="?section=B&status=p"> CC</a>
    <a href="?section=X&status=p"> AQ</a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: @Coffee Awesome, happy to help! If the solution worked, could you please consider accepting as the answer? Thank you!